# Pyside2: Tab is not "properly" highlighted, when starting application

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I have a Tab widget in my application. When I start the application the starting tab is always grey, rather than blue.

[image]

Only when I click on the tab I will start to be blue.

[image]

I want the tab to be blue right from the start.
Setting the Tab Index does not appear to help.

`self.tab.setCurrentIndex(0)`

Comment: That seems the result of an inactive window. Is the window of that tab widget the active one? Can you please provide a [mre] so that we can check if nothing else is stealing focus from that window?